# Interesting C++ dependency injection scheme

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

**Background:** I am a novice in C++. I have a C# project that I want to convert to C++ to gain some experience in writing some useful C++ code, beyond textbook examples. To this end, I have examined the code of some open source projects to get the feel of real C++, and also tried to do some refactoring in a fairly old project with some valgrind action and some adhoc statistics in debug build to confirm correctness (all with real input). (I have done a college project in C++ a number of years ago, but I don't count that as any real experience).

**Actual question:**

The C# project I am trying to convert to C++ uses lite weight dependency injection. Every class receives a "context" object in the constructor. It first inserts itself into the "context" before querying its own dependencies so that circular dependencies are not a problem.

After some pondering I came up with a following scheme in C++. Every DI object receives its dependencies by reference in the constructor. I make all DI objects fields in one class (by value as sub-objects) and wire them up in the initialization list.

```cpp
// Yes, the project is compiler for a toy programming language
class Compiler {
    Logger log;
    Options options;
    ParserDriver parserDriver;
    DeclarationAnalysis declarationAnalysis;
    CodeTypeAnalysis codeTypeAnalysis;
    FlowAnalysis flowAnalysis;
    CodeGeneration codeGeneration;
    Check check;
    Typings typings;
    Operators operators;
    Symtab symtab;
public:
    Compiler();
};

Compiler::Compiler() :
    log(),
    options(),
    parserDriver(log),
    declarationAnalysis(log, symtab, check),
    codeTypeAnalysis(log, symtab, operators, typings, check),
    flowAnalysis(log),
    codeGeneration(typings, symtab),
    check(log, symtab),
    typings(symtab),
    operators(symtab, log, typings),
    symtab()
{}

// Example DI object
class DeclarationAnalysis {
    Logger* log;
    Symtab* symtab;
    Check* check;
public:
    DeclarationAnalysis(Logger&, Symtab&, Check&);
}

DeclarationAnalysis::DeclarationAnalysis(Logger& log, Symtab& symtab, Check& chack) 
    : log(&log), symtab(&symtab), check(&check) {}
```

Is code like this correct in a sense that it's safe, without undefined behavior (eg. `symtab` is initialized last but given as argument to other field's constructors)? It seems very elegant at first sight. Memory is packed, can even be allocated on the stack. Have I rediscovered an existing pattern?

Comment: If you're asking for improvement and review of already working code, you should rather refer to [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions). For Stack Overflow your question looks _to broad_.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list: *"non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition"* - so your use of `symtab` is not safe

Comment: You might be interested some dependency injection framework in C++. [fruit](https://github.com/google/fruit/wiki/tutorial:-getting-started) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor initialization lists are called in order the objects exist in the class.  Compilers can be set to warn.if the constructor list is a different order.  Turn that on.

You can take references to uninitialized values and pass them around.  Anything besides storing a pointer or reference to those uninitialized objects is not a good plan.

In your sample code you are storing pointers only.  That is safe.

The destructors of those types cannot assume the pointed-to objects exist, as part way through `Compiler` construction it could fail (via exception) and cause destruction of the already-constructed subobjects.  This is difficult to get right.

Comment: So if I reorder the init list such that all fields are initialized before given as arguments to other constructors, it's safe even if I use the objects in said constructors?

Comment: @irpbc the order of construxtion.is the irder *in the class* not in the list at construction; sorry, I was unclear.

Comment: Oh... OK I got it now :), the order is in the order of declaration in the class body. That solves the question.